# Unable to change from one activity to another(page gets reloaded)on in Android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, reload

The same activity gets reloaded after a button click which was intended to another activity but works fine for the first time of execution . The code is quite normal and basic but not able to know the problem

```
public void init() {
    ImageButton driver = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.driver);
    driver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent login = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Driverlogin.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    } // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used. SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); init(); } 
}
```

Comment: We would like to see `code is normal and basic` this. Also if you have error logs share them

Comment: @shashi sekhar Please add your normal and basic code

Comment: Updated my question please check.

Comment: No error logs . App is good and running

Answer (score 1):

```
public void init() 
{ 
    ImageButton driver=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.driver); 
    driver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) 
        { 
            Intent login=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Driverlogin.class); 
            startActivity(login); 
        } 
    });
}

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); 

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
    { 
        checkLocationPermission(); 
    } 
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used. 
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); init(); 
}
```